# MSI uninstall : get message component will not be removed, so that icon will not be removed

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, uninstallation, shortcut-file

I have basic MSI project that 2 or more versions of it can be installed in parallel
Each one to a different location except for a single exe which is shared and has a shortcut in the desktop.

In version 1.0 MSI I have
Component – install files to \Program Files\prod_1.0
Shared files component A - install exe to \Program Files\prod_shared
Shared shortcut component B - create a shortcut on desktop to exe in component A

In version 2.0 MSI I have
Component – install files to \Program Files\prod_2.0
Shared files component A - install exe to \Program Files\prod_shared
Shared shortcut component B - create a shortcut on desktop to exe in component A

The component GUID are the same for both MSI versions and the icon I’m using in the Shared shortcut component isn’t used by other shortcuts.
The problem I have is that if I have 2 version? installed in parallel and then I uninstall one version I want the desktop shortcut will be removed.
I added this line to the code
MsiSetComponentState(hMSI,"Shared_Shortcut_Desktop",INSTALLSTATE_ABSENT);

But when I uninstall I get this message
component will not be removed, so that 'NewShortcut74_AE5D17DE4C4B4737ABB20A0D0358B69E.exe' icon will not be removed.

Any idea how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

If those two shortcuts have the same component guid then unless there's something else you've not said, it really is just a shared component, and because it's shared by both setups then uninstalling one of them won't remove it. If you had a shared file with the same component id installed to (say) the same CommonFiles folder location then the same rule would be applied - it wouldn't remove the file because it's in use by the other product. The short answer is to use a different guid (and rename it too, maybe with the product version).

What's the reference to MsiSetComponentState got to do with this? It implies you've written some code to try to remove that component, but MSI won't remove it if it's shared anyway.